# How to compile TOC manually before running pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, python

I made a script that generates some tex code. Since i started using 
`{tocbibind}` the command `pdflatex', '-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmod` 
started having strange behaviours. My python script runs that cmd and generates a pdf with a missing TOC. The second time I generate a pdf with the same name, he detects the previously generated toc files and does the job. This is not very ecological, i am basically required to run the command twice since I use table of contents .

There's a way/command to only generate .toc files? So I can then then run the final pdflatex command.I would be very appreciated

I implemented the toc in a very similar way as in: https://youtu.be/pLol-ORCQ_8

Comment: As it currently is, this is standard latex behavoir. We have been runing latex thrice (or even more), if you want TOC, bibliography, in-document hyperlinks. Glossaries and other things might add even more. That's why latex build applications (such as `latexmk` or `arara`) exist. At last with `latexmk` you'd get as many latex runs, as needed, but not more (in 99.99% of cases).

Comment: OK, I really can generate that toc files via script and be more 'ecollogical'. They are pretty simple. But if such command exists I would like to know.

Comment: tables of contents typically involve page numbers and you can not know them without fully typesetting the text.

Comment: @ANormalUser: You *can* generate your own ToC file for use by the current job, but that may change during the compilation of your file. What typically happens though is that there's an initial requirement to compile *twice*, but after that there's minimal requirement to compile twice as the document structure "settles." [`latexmk`](//mg.readthedocs.io/latexmk.html) automates the process of recompiling, if needed. There's also [`rerunfilecheck`](//ctan.org/pkg/rerunfilecheck) that adds warnings you can check for if you want to code that into your Python script(s).